# AWS Linux image - where to put application directory?

Tags: linux, directory-structure, aws

I need to install my application files in the linux server.

Where should I put the files? and what are the permission that I should set?
Can I put them at /var/app? (AWS Beanstalk put the app at /var/app/current)

I also need some resources files (.json) that should be accessed via my application code.
Where can I put them? is it OK to put them at /usr/local/src? and if yes, should the permission be root or the same as I set in the app files?

Comment: Traditionally you'd keep your applications and data in /opt, /usr/local, or maybe somewhere under /var. But anywhere is fine. The OS doesn't care.

Comment: Remember that the OS disk provided with an Amazon instance may be considered temporary.  If you plan on destroying and rebuilding VMs then you may want to look into a second persistent elastic block storage device (e.g. attached as `sdc`) and mount that.  In that way you can replace your AWS instance but keep your applications and data.